# Stop WPF Application from moving upon reaching end of scroll

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-8, datagridview

I have a WPF 4.0 C# application using a DataGridView inside a WindowsFormHost control. This is all working fine but on Windows 8.1 when I scroll to the end of the datagridview the whole WPF application frame moves visually to indicate the end of the scrolling. I want to disable this.

This seems to be a similar problem but the solution does not work for me:

https://antonidol.wordpress.com/2012/01/24/how-to-stop-a-wpf-window-from-moving-by-removing-the-manipulationboundaryfeedback/

I tried to attach the following event handler to the Window, Grid and WindowsFormHost but the event did not seem to get fired.

```
Grid_Control.ManipulationBoundaryFeedback += delegate(object sendera, ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEventArgs ea)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Testa");
    ea.Handled = true;
};
```

Comment: Solution: remove the winforms stuff and use WPF.

Comment: @HighCore You'll be delighted to know it is also happening when I use a DataGrid. And I need to use the DataGridView due to great performance differences.